# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zza(Landroid/content/Context;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zzc; or its super classes

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

I'm trying to use firebase-core library in my Android project but it keeps giving me this NoSuchMethodError in my released apk. However, it works fine in emulator. The exception message is this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zza(Landroid/content/Context;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zzc; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.zzc' appears in /data/app/com.xxxx.xxxx/base.apk): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfx.zzs(Unknown Source)
```

I added firebase-core:16.0.7 using Android studio's firebase assistant. And my gradle file is as follow:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This line applies the com.android.application plugin. Note that you should
 * only apply the com.android.application plugin. Applying the Java plugin as
 * well will result in a build error.
 */
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

/**
 * This dependencies block includes any dependencies for the project itself. The
 * following line includes all the JAR files in the libs directory.
 */
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    compile project(':Shared')
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile files('libs/js.jar')
    compile files('libs/gps-stripped.jar')
    compile files('libs/antlr-runtime-3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/logback-android-1.1.1-6.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar')
    compile 'com.github.jsqlparser:jsqlparser:0.9.6'
    compile files('libs/Android-Languages.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

/**
 * The android{} block configures all of the parameters for the Android build.
 * You must provide values for at least the build tools version and the
 * compilation target.
 */
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        //instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        /**
         * Move the build types to build-types/<type>
         * For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
         * This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
         * conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
         * Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
         * by a similar customization.
         */
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/license.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zoe sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Well, AS won't do squat without the gradle file so.... I've had this problem previously and can't remember what I did to solve it and am just happy to not have it now lol. Google has so much crap now that it gets difficult to weed through all of it. Might need the X libraries, might not, might need to list all the conflicting libraries because it can't deal with it, etc. Its a royal pain now =)